# Azure Active directory domain name not resolvoing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a primary domain in azure called `somename.onmicrosoft.com` but its not resolving to any IP.

This is the default domain that is available and a new one can't be created. I'm trying to join VM's to this domain. But nslookup doesn't resolve the address `somename.onmicrosoft.com`.

Any idea what I need to do in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

when you signup to azure you will get a default directory with onmicrosoft.com domain and it will be your primary domain. You can't change or delete the initial domain name, but you can add your organization's names as a custom domain. Adding custom domain names helps you to create user names that are familiar to your users, such as abc@yourorg.com. but you can not domain join virtual machines to azure ad.

To add virtual machines to domain You need to have active directory domain controller running in on-premise or in azure. If you don't have an on-Prem setup you can deploy azure adds managed instance and add your virtual machines to the ADDS domain.

Please check this to  [Create and configure an Azure Active Directory Domain Services managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance)

Please go through below links to find the difference between

[Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis?WT.mc_id=ITOPSTALK-BLOG-PIERRER)

[Azure Active directory domain services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview?WT.mc_id=ITOPSTALK-BLOG-PIERRER)

[Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/virtual-dc/active-directory-domain-services-overview?WT.mc_id=ITOPSTALK-BLOG-PIERRER)